# React native: horizontal swipe-scene pagination with dynamic loading

Tags: react-native

I want to implement horizontal swipe-scene-pagination in react-native app. I need it to have only 3 pages rendered at any moment (current, previous and next) and i want to add new pages dynamically on page change.
I bet there are implementation for that is already done by someone, but i haven't found any.

Also, as far as i remember, this kind of questions are not allowed in stackoverflow. Could you, please, point to the stack-exchange site where i can ask this question?